# Wireless communication w/o Wi-Fi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I am trying to make a system where six people sit on six computers entering data through a web application. In my current implementation of this system, these six computers are connected through a local network switch using ethernet cables. One of these six computers runs a server which serves the website to the other computers. **I am prohibited from creating a Wi-Fi network (not due to security concerns, rather the event venue does not allow it.)**

While the system works, it is kind of a pain to manage these cables. It takes place in a high traffic area with limited space (a basketball stadium), so I was wondering if there is any product such as "wireless ethernet." Meaning, an interface that communicates via Bluetooth or some other method, but will allow the computer to connect to the network switch wirelessly **(still without creating a Wi-Fi network)** Does such a device exist?

I apologize if this is a very elementary question; I am just a hobbyist programmer w/o much knowledge on networking.

Comment: They probably don't allow wireless due to possible interference issues. I'd be more concerned about the venue's rules and understanding the scope of them, before seeking another wireless technology. They may not allow anything you are seeking.

Comment: @Appleoddity the rules say the following `Teams may not set up their own 802.11a/b/g/n/ac (2.4GHz or
5GHz) wireless communication`. Does this include Bluetooth?

Comment: Well, it's not 802.11a/b/g/n but it is on 2.4Ghz.

Comment: Depending where you are in the world they are probably not legally allowed to stop you from setting up wireless -https://consumerist.com/2015/08/18/company-fined-750k-for-blocking-wifi-hotspots-at-convention-centers/

Comment: Thanks for the help @Appleoddity. I just confirmed that Bluetooth **is** allowed, just not Wi-Fi. And davidgo, I'm afraid it isn't too practical for me to sue them.. if only :(

Comment: Wireless Ethernet is 802.11 which is "Wi-Fi".  You are not going to be able to build a network with Bluetooth.  You can always use the cellular network

Comment: I'm not sure you'll spend *less* effort setting up a non-802.11 solution than just running network cables.

Comment: Wireless technology varies quite a bit. You haven't mentioned what kind of range you are looking at. Range of the technology will also be limited by interference and objects.  Bluetooth sounds like the way to go, but it is limited in range. Read here about how it works: http://ntrg.cs.tcd.ie/undergrad/4ba2.05/group3/ and here is a google search about setting it up. https://www.google.com/search?q=bluetooth+personal+area+network+windows+howto I haven't done it before.

Comment: @Ramhound Your comment is a little confusing. It sorta looks like you are grouping bluetooth with wifi and 802.11. Just want to make sure we are clear that Bluetooth is 802.15.

Comment: **so I was wondering if there is any product such as "wireless ethernet."** - I was responding to this statement.  The author can "mean" anything they want but words have specific meaning, and wireless Ethernet, is 802.11 not 802.15

Answer (score 1):

Look at using Ethernet over Power devices.

Comment: Ethernet over Power requires power outlets, no? The event is held in an arena, and we will be sitting in the stands, so I'm not sure this will work out.

Comment: All of the computers would need to plug into a common electrical circuit, i.e. on the same breaker. If this isn't possible, this solution isn't for you.

Answer (score 0):

As someone mentioned in the comments, 802.11 (Wi-Fi) *is* wireless Ethernet. The Wi-Fi Alliance had originally called themselves WECA, the "Wireless Ethernet Compatibility Alliance", before they created the "Wi-Fi" trademark.

Some creative options, depending on budget:

1. You could buy 4G/LTE USB dongles for each of the laptops, and maybe host the server on the Internet ("in the cloud"). Would require a multi-line data plan from a wireless carrier. Oh hey, you could make sure each person has the data tethering (sometimes called personal hotspot) feature enabled on their smartphone's wireless plan, and tether via USB or Bluetooth instead of Wi-Fi. Anyway, between USB dongle wireless modems, or smartphone tethering, you have a lot of options depending on how much of a hardware and service budget you have. You might have to do some extra battery management to make sure this solution can last for a 3 hour game or all-day tournament or however long it needs to last. Also consider buying laptops with this functionality built-in, or tablets with this functionality built-in (possibly in conjunction with keyboard covers/cases or Bluetooth keyboards, if keyboards are necessary for the data entry).
2. 60GHz 802.11ad "WiGig" devices are on the market now. Since WiGig uses the 60GHz band and not 2.4GHz or 5GHz, it doesn't seem to violate the letter of the law. Note that WiGig APs usually include 802.11a/b/g/n/ac AP functionality, so you'd have to be sure to turn off that disallowed functionality and only enable WiGig. Note also that the Wi-Fi Alliance is who certified WiGig, and they even call it "Wi-Fi CERTIFIED WiGig" (emphasis theirs), so if the wording of the rule were updated to actually say "Wi-Fi", this *might* break the rule.
3. Thinking outside the box: Have a mobile UI wiz make a custom mobile app that allows you to do the data entry quickly from a touch interface instead of requiring a full-on laptop with keyboard and trackpad. If you made a cool smartphone app for quickly entering game stats and the backend server it reports to, you could probably sell/license that shit to tons of teams around the world at the high school, college, and pro levels.

**Edited to add:** Oh, I just saw your profile and now I'm guessing that this is probably about robotics competitions that happen to take place in basketball stadiums, not basketball itself. In that case, I'm less enthusiastic about the potential licensing revenue for idea #3. :-)